# Retrieve image URLs from JSON and convert them into array of UIimage

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, uiimage

Recently I try to extract lots of images URLs from JSON and convert them into array of UIimage. But this process will slowdown when I implemented lazy loading. Can I speed this process up with the help of Alamofireimage or any other way? Thanks

Comment: Yes that is in fact the right way. Libraries like AlamofireImage and SDWebImage cache images that are downloaded from different urls.

Comment: so my JSON objects is paginated, once reach the bottom I need to fetch bunch of new images from second page. The problem is I need them to be in array of UIimages, anything I can speed it up?

Comment: Just pass on the image urls to the second page. These libraries will handle the image loading from these urls for you. Storing images in an array is a bad practice.

Comment: Yes I know but because I am doing Pinterest layout, the layout delegate function need to know the images height only can create the layout, you get what I mean?

Comment: Yes I get it and it’s a tricky requirement. Can’t you get the images’ sizes in the json objects along with urls?

Comment: I use [Imaginary](https://github.com/hyperoslo/Imaginary) to load images and cache them. Cache can reduce some downloading tasks.

Comment: @kiki your approach is not correct. as Adeel says storing images in an array is extremely bad practice. Not only in terms of network calls but also memory usage. Since you have JSON anyway, you can set your database structure to save the image sizes as well. Then when fetching the image URLs you can also fetch their sizes and prepare the collectionView accordingly.

Comment: @GaloTorresSevilla how to save the image size without backend provide me the sizes?

Comment: @kiki I’m not sure where exactly you are getting the JSON from but if you are setting up a web service or something similar a quick js could help you check the image sizes and throw the values in JSON as well. If your JSON is coming from a database it’s even easier because the image sizes can be just two added fields.